# How to redirect sub-domain not found?

Tags: php, 301-redirect, subdomain, 404

Suppose my site - `example.com` had a subdomain - `subdomain.example.com` which I have deleted.

How do I redirect the not found error in PHP or the mod_rewrite (.htaccess)?

Comment: You have to have the sub-domain defined. When a request comes to your web-server it needs to know how to handle it. Otherwise it would be ignored completely and there will be **no** opportunity to redirect it. You will need to set-up a CNAME and define it on your websever. *Then* you can redirect your sub-domain to where ever you want to.